# de qual instancia emitir eventos ? socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

Apartir de qual instancia eu deveria emitir eventos para as conexões do websocket?

socket.to() ou io.to() ?

Lendo a seção [Server instance](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-instance/) da documentação do socket.io, percebi que em nenhum exemplo é utilizado a instancia do server (io) para emitir eventos; todos os exemplos que vi, é emitido apartir da [instancia do socket](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-socket-instance/) (socket).

Dei uma pesquisada no chatGPT, e ele repassou que o correto é emitir apartir da instancia do server (io), pois assim, faz com que chegue em todas as conexões da *room*.

Eu testei usando as duas formas, e em ambas, os eventos foram emitidos para todas conexões da *room* (2 conectadas no mesmo server).

Então fiquei na duvida, em um cenario onde meu servidor websocket está escalado, ambas formas vao se comportar igual ?

```
io.adapter(Redis.createAdapter(pubClient, subClient));
io.on('connection', socket => {

    socket.on("novo-pedido", (params) => {

        const dadosDoPedido = {
            foo: "bar"
        }

        socket.to("loja-10").emit("pedidoLojista", dadosDoPedido);
        io.to("loja-10").emit("pedidoLojista", dadosDoPedido);

    })

})
```